# Is it possible to use the Microchip Graphics library for a Single Color GLCD?

Tags: pic, microchip, glcd

I didn't seam to see the controller for those simple GLCDs on the list of controllers for the microchip graphics library.

Does it support such libraries, or do i have to create a custom controller to support such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own graphics "driver" that integrates seamlessly with the Microchip Graphics Library, for any graphics LCD you have. I was able to use the graphics library with a different type of color LCD that the library did not support by default.

The process is as follows:

1. Download the Graphics LCD library from microchip
2. Make a copy of an existing "driver" code file/folder (I'm not sure if I found the exact files/folders, but you get the idea)

   - see `Lib\Object Layer\Configs\XXX.c` and `Lib\Primitive Layer\Configs\XXX.c`
   - see `Lib\S1D13517\`
3. Modify the code to reflect the exact protocol the LCD needs (refer to its datasheet)

   - Typically serial and parallel LCDs are supported (for parallel LCDs, the PMP / Parallel Master Port module is useful)
   - Start with the "init" function, and be able to send the commands it needs to initialise
   - After that try sending commands to set a pixel, which will be used to draw lines, curves, rectangles, etc
   - If the LCD supports accellerated primitives like lines/curves, then you can modify the driver file to directly send those. Otherwise leave the defaults (uses the set pixel function)
   - For text, you can choose font to embed in your app and the library will draw text with that font